# Graph of sequence

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to graph a sequence `g[n]`.
I tried:

```
{g[n_] := FindSequenceFunction[{5, 11, 19, 29}, n]
Plot[g[n],n,1,99999]}
```

But it did not work.

Comment: From this post it's hard to tell whether you had trouble finding the sequence, or plotting it. Consideration of that issue might lead to a better-formulated question, if not actual working code.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot parentheses in the second argument of `Plot`:

```
g[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[{5, 11, 19, 29}, n] ;
Plot[g[n], {n, 1, 99999}]
```

Notice that I changed `:=` to `=` such that the sequence function is found once, rather than every single time that `Plot` wants to evaluate `g` at a new sample point.

In order to plot for natural numbers only, use

```
DiscretePlot[g[n], {n, 1, 49}]
```

Comment: how to restrict domain to natural numbers.

Comment: @Theodor I edited the answer

Comment: or `ListPlot[g[n] /. n -> Range[20]]`